# How to import custom log file from Azure App Service into Azure Monitor

Tags: .net, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-log-analytics

I have a .Net App Hosted in Azure as a Web App. This app writes custom logs to a file stored in the root directory of the site using Serilog. I am hoping to find a way to get this log file ingested into Azure Monitor and setup email alerts so when specific lines(error events) of the file are detected it will shoot off an email. I have tried setting up custom logs in Azure Monitor following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/data-sources-custom-logs) However when attempting to run a query, no results are found. Anyone have any tips or can point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Can you provide more details about your setup? And, if you think it's an issue with your code or query, provide an [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the best approaches to meet your needs is to use [Azure Log Analytics HTTP Data Collector API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/data-collector-api) that sends the customized logs to the Azure Log Analytics Workspace resource.

Sample Code:

```
    // Send a request to the POST API endpoint
    public static void PostData(string signature, string date, string json) {
    try {
    string url = "https://" + customerId + ".ods.opinsights.azure.com/api/logs?api-version=2016-04-01";
    System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(); 
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json"); 
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Log-Type", LogName); 
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", signature); 
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-date", date); 
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("time-generated-field", TimeStampField);  
    
    System.Net.Http.HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8); 
    httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"); 
    Task<System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage> response = client.PostAsync(new Uri(url), httpContent); 
    System.Net.Http.HttpContent responseContent = response.Result.Content; string result = responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result; 
    Console.WriteLine("Return Result: " + result); 
    }
     catch (Exception excep) { 
     Console.WriteLine("API Post Exception: " + excep.Message); 
     } }
```