# How to gather custom logs from Azure web app to Log analytics?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-monitoring

I have a .net core app which is deployed to Azure web app based on the Windows platform. In my app, I'm using Serilog for logs and I have these settings to send the specific log format to this location: **../../LogFiles/Application/diagnostics-.txt**. I have set the diagnostics settings. Why I can not see any data from the table **AppServiceAppLogs**?

This is my serilog's setting

```
"WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Async",
        "Args": {
          "configure": [
            {
              "Name": "File",
              "Args": {
                "path": "../../LogFiles/Application/diagnostics-.txt",
                "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz}] [{ApplicationName}] [{Version}] [{Environment}] [{ClientAgent}] [{CorrelationId}] [{Level}] [{SourceContext}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",
                "rollingInterval": "Day",
                "retainedFileCountLimit": 100
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
```

Here is an example log: [2023-10-10 10:10:25.788 +00:00] [supportMs] [0] [Uat2] [Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36] [00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000] [Error] [CacheManager.RedisCacheManager] xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

I want to collect custom logs from Azure web app and show logs in log analytics workspace

Comment: 1)Make sure you have created  Log Analytics workspace in Azure , if yes then collect the workspace ID and primary key and add in your code 
2)you have installed all the required packages
3)Setup Azure Monitor by adding the Send to Log Analytics and select AppServiceAppLogs
4)Azure Diagnostic Settings:
   - Go to your Azure Web App in the Azure Portal.
   - Under `Monitoring`, select `App Service logs`.
   - make sure that `Application Logging (Filesystem)` is turned on. The Quota and Retention Period can be configured according to your preference.

Comment: @JalpaPanchal Which logs provider are you using? I did the same as you said with serilog, but the table AppServiceAppLogs doesn't show in Log Analytics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Azure Log analytics workspace we need to create DCR with our Windows or Linux Agent and only the below Resource Types are directly supported for creating DCR where Azure App service is not present:-

[image]

I have implemented **serilog logic in my `Asp.net` core app** the simplest way **to retrieve the serilog logs in Log analytics is to write them in Console** like below:-

Added below code in my Program.cs file:-

```cs
builder.Host.UseSerilog((context, config) =>
{
    config.WriteTo.Console(); 
});
```

Local the Logs are visible in the local console:-

[image]

**Added a Diagnostic Setting to send the logs to Azure Log analytics workspace and the same logs were visible like below:-**

[image]

[image]

In order to meet your requirement, You can add serilog to a file  like below:-

```cs
builder.Host.UseSerilog((context, config) =>
{
    config.WriteTo.File(".log"); // Replace 'path-to-log-file.log' with your desired file path.
});
```

.log file is created while deploying my Azure web app like below:-

[image]

Now, implement the logic from this [SO thread answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69052298/how-to-import-custom-log-file-from-azure-app-service-into-azure-monitor) in your .net app to send this custom logs file data. But the API in the Answer is going to get deprecated. **Instead use Azure Log Ingestion API [**here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/monitor.ingestion-readme?view=azure-dotnet) and Add it in your .Net app.**

For more clarity on Azure Log Ingestion API you can refer the steps [**here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/tutorial-logs-ingestion-portal) for Azure Portal.

Additionally, After implementing the above Log ingestion code in your .net app, you can also create a custom table in your log analytics workspace with the sample data from your log file like below:-

[image]

Convert your Log file into json and then upload it as a sample like below so Log analytics understands the schema:-

[image]

Now, Click Next and Create the Custom Table.

Use the same DCR, DCE and custom table in your Azure Log Ingestion code refer below:-

```cs
var endpoint = new Uri("<data_collection_endpoint>");
var ruleId = "<data_collection_rule_id>";
var streamName = "<stream_name>";

var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
LogsIngestionClient client = new(endpoint, credential);
DateTimeOffset currentTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;

//custom log code binary data
BinaryData data = BinaryData.FromObjectAsJson(
// custom log code

// Upload our logs
Response response = await client.UploadAsync(
    ruleId,
    streamName,
    RequestContent.Create(data)).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have two questions: 1.After you set serilog to write custom logs in console. How do you retrieve the custom logs in log analytics workspace? The screenshot you shows is 'AppServiceHTTPLogs' table which doesn't contain any custom logs. 2.Actually I already made it by using Application Insights to collect custom logs. Which method do you recommend to use when considering costs? (Application Insights or Azure Log Ingestion API)